# Google plus Request URI issue

Tags: iphone, google-plus

In my application I am using google plus to share things. Here when I press sign in button, it require for email/password and then after login press I got following error.

[image]

I have created application using following steps

[image]

How do I get right solution and can share things on G+ wall?

I am using following redirect url, which are in my application of G+

```
signInButton_.scope = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",@"http://localhost", nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`scope` property](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/api/interface_g_p_p_sign_in_button#a30f0c6d798e83adf53d134a19d8a6c79) is not a list of redirect URIs, rather the property is a list of OAuth scopes that list the permissions that you will ask the user to grant. The basic scope that you should request for sign in is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me` to get the user's public Google+ identity.

You would list other scopes for access to other services, for example for Google calendar you'd list `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly`. Find the appropriate Google REST API documentation that you are interested in to see the scope required for that service.

By [setting a URL type with a URL scheme using your bundle ID](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started#add_a_url_type), your app registers itself as a handler for that scheme (bundle ID). After sharing, Google+ attempts to send your user back to your app by using the bundle ID that you registered in the Console project. [More info on URL schemes](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html).

Answer (score 0):

After long search on it i got the solution for this issues. The solution is that we need to **set Bundel Identifier same as in the application**. If you set different identifier then this kinds of issue is raise.

Also please set the following scope for SignIn

```
 signInButton_.scope = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",
                       nil];
```

If you want to come back in you application after login and sharing please **set URLScheme from the Info**

[image]